# Apache POI Chart Data Label Font Size

Tags: charts, apache-poi, pie-chart

How do you set the font size of the date labels for the pie chart - Below is the code - the number displayed inside the pies sections are pretty small to read . I was able to adjust the legend and chart title font but not the values displayed for actual pie values .

```
    XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, startColumn, 0, endColumn, 13);

    XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
    chart.setTitleText(ChartTitle);
    chart.getTitle().getBody().getParagraph(0).addDefaultRunProperties().setFontSize(17d);
     
    XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
    legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT);
    XDDFTextBody legendTextBody = new XDDFTextBody(legend);
    legendTextBody.getXmlObject().addNewBodyPr();
    legendTextBody.addNewParagraph().addDefaultRunProperties().setFontSize(14d);
    legend.setTextBody(legendTextBody);
    
    ArrayList<String>  chartKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> chartValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Iterator hmIterator = map.entrySet().iterator();       
    while (hmIterator.hasNext()) {           
        Map.Entry mapElement
        = (Map.Entry)hmIterator.next();
        chartKeys.add(mapElement.getKey().toString());
        chartValues.add((Integer)mapElement.getValue());
 }
    
    XDDFDataSource<String> cat = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(chartKeys.toArray(new String[chartKeys.size()]));
    XDDFDataSource<Integer> val = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(chartValues.toArray(new Integer[chartValues.size()]));

    XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.PIE, null, null);
    data.setVaryColors(true);
    XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(cat, (XDDFNumericalDataSource<? extends Number>) val);
    series.setTitle(chartHeader, null);
    if (!chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).isSetDLbls()) {
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDLbls();
    }
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowVal().setVal(true);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowBubbleSize().setVal(true);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowPercent().setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
    chart.plot(data);
```

[image]

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for the response . Not sure whether I understood what you are referring to here . I am using to write to an xlsx not word document . Just want to see if there is a way to increase the font size of those numbers its too small - I was able to change the font size of the headers , chart title legends etc but not those numbers/alues displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache POI, up to now, not provides all what Microsoft Office provides.
So this question mainly is: "How to do things not provided by Apache POI in it's high level classes?

The answer is: There are low level `org.openxmlformats.schemas.*` classes created from Microsoft's XSD files using [XMLBeans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/). Those classes contain all what Microsoft describes in it's XSDs.

How to use the the low level `org.openxmlformats.schemas..*` classes?

Unfortunately there is no API documentation online available. But we need this. So we need downloading the sources of used `ooxml-schemas-*.jar` (up to Apache PPOI 4) or `poi-ooxml-full jar` (since Apache POI 5). Then we can create a API documentation using `javadoc`.

All Office Open XML files, so also `*.xlsx`, are simply ZIP archives. So one can unzip a `*.xlsx` file using a ZIP application (7-Zip can do that for example). Then we can have a look into the internals.

---

To find out what to do for charts in `*.xlsx` when high level classes of Apache POI lack support for something, do the following:

Create a `*.xlsx` having a chart using what Apache POI provides.

- You have done that already.

Then unzip that `*.xlsx` and show the content of `xl/chart/chart*.xml`. Then open that `*.xlsx`  in Excel GUI and do what you want to do additionally. Then save. Then unzip that `*.xlsx` and show the content of `xl/chart/chart*.xml`. Now compare what has changed in XML. Now the need is to recreate those changes using code.

At first try to understand what `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.*` classes needed. In XML the elements most are *C*omplex*T*ypes. So if you find an element `chart` in XML the corresponding class is `CTChart`. An XML element `plotArea` is `CTPlotArea`. XML `pieChart` is `CTPieChart` and so on.

Knowing this and having created the API documentation using `javadoc`, one should be able to figure out which methods of which classes to use to create what is required.

---

To your current concrete requirement to increase the font size for data labels:

Unzip the `*.xlsx` created by your current code and show the content of `xl/chart/chart*.xml`.  You will find something like

```xml
<c:dLbls>
 <c:showLegendKey val="false"/>
 <c:showVal val="true"/>
 <c:showCatName val="false"/>
 <c:showSerName val="false"/>
 <c:showPercent val="false"/>
 <c:showBubbleSize val="true"/>
</c:dLbls>
```

for the data labels.

Then open that `*.xlsx`  in Excel GUI and do what you want to do additionally. Increase the font size for data labels to 16pt for example. Then save. Then unzip that `*.xlsx` and show the content of `xl/chart/chart*.xml`. You will find something like

```xml
<c:dLbls>
 <c:txPr>
  <a:bodyPr >...</a:bodyPr>
  <a:p>
   <a:pPr>
    <a:defRPr sz="1600"/>
   </a:pPr>
  </a:p>
 </c:txPr>
 <c:showLegendKey val="0"/>
...
</c:dLbls>
```

for the data labels.

Now compare what has changed in XML:

The data lable (`dLbls`) now have text properties (`txPr`). The text properties have body properties (`bodyPr`). And the text properties have a paragraph `p`. The paragraph has paragraph properties (`pPr`). The paragraph properties have defined run properties (`defRPr` )  and there a size of `1600` is set.

Now the need is to recreate those changes using code.

```java
...
chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewTxPr();
chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().getTxPr().addNewBodyPr();
chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().getTxPr().addNewP();
chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().getTxPr().getPArray(0).addNewPPr();
chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().getTxPr().getPArray(0).getPPr().addNewDefRPr().setSz(1600);  
...
```